# LESS CSS - Mixin Arguments and Nth-Child - without looping

Tags: css, css-selectors, arguments, less, less-mixins

I am trying to write a less argument that will associate with the id #p0x1. I would like to be able to write an argument like

```
@ytrans = translateY(@argument * 2)
```

then provide that argument value for each ID.

```
#p0x1(@argument:3){@ytrans}
```

However, I am unable to do this with the nth-child css. I've only seen solutions that solve this problem with a loop. Is there a more direct manner of approaching this like this?

```
#p0x1 div:nth-child(1)(@argument:3){
```

---

Here is the code that I currently have.

```
/*Cube Position 0,1*/

#p0x1 div:nth-child(1) {
  transform         : @zaxis @ytrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p0x1 div:nth-child(2) {
  transform         : @top @zaxis @ytrans;  
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p0x1 div:nth-child(3) {
  transform         : @back @zaxis @ytrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p0x1 div:nth-child(4) {
  transform         : @bottom @zaxis @ytrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p0x1 div:nth-child(5) {
    transform: @left @zaxis @ytrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p0x1 div:nth-child(6)  {
    transform         : @right @zaxis @ytrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find this solution with the help of a brilliant individual name [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) who helped me with my [prior problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856323/less-create-id-by-looping-through-two-variables).

---

## My Solution

```
.coordinates(-2, 2);
     .coordinates(@min, @max) {
    .xcoor; .xcoor(@xcoor: @min) when (@xcoor <= @max) {
        .ycoor; .xcoor(@xcoor + 1);
    }
    .ycoor(@ycoor: @min) when (@ycoor <= @max) {
        @ytrans:translatey(@cubesize * @ycoor);
        @xtrans:translatex(@cubesize * @xcoor);
#p@{xcoor}x@{ycoor} div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: @zaxis @ytrans @xtrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p@{xcoor}x@{ycoor} div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: @top @zaxis @ytrans @xtrans;   
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p@{xcoor}x@{ycoor} div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: @back @zaxis @ytrans @xtrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p@{xcoor}x@{ycoor} div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: @bottom @zaxis @ytrans @xtrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p@{xcoor}x@{ycoor} div:nth-child(5) {
    transform: @left @zaxis @ytrans @xtrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
#p@{xcoor}x@{ycoor} div:nth-child(6)  {
    transform: @right @zaxis @ytrans @xtrans;
    background-image: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
        .ycoor(@ycoor + 1);
    }
}
```

[Output of more than 60,000 lines](http://pastebin.com/BKWCktVn)

This is why I love preprocessors for CSS. If anyone has suggestions for improvements then I would welcome them.

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood your question, but the answer still uses loops (two infact).

Comment: You're absolutely right. My ignorance led me to believe that looping would be less efficient when customizing on each nth-child node. That ignorance was my mistake. That said, a good point was made that this is purely experimental. No one should use 60,000 lines for a web application.